# Import PostgreSQL view to Entity Framework

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, view, edmx

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and PostgreSQL. I generated a Database and now i need to import a View inside my .edmx designer, but the problem is that i get an exception, because EF wasn't able to import the view because there is no explicit key inside of it. I've tried to add a Key column inside the view as someone else told me to do, but i got still the error (error code 6013) and i did not found a solution to my problem yet. Is there something i can do to import my view? Thanks.

My view query:

```
"TableA"."Id",
"TableB"."Label",
"TableC"."Name" AS "TableCName",
"TableC"."ColumnCode",
"TableA_TableC"."IdTableC",
"TableA_TableC"."Value",
"TableA"."Name",
"TableA"."InternalCode",
"TableA"."InternalName"
FROM
(
    (
        (
            "TableA"
            JOIN "TableA_TableC" ON (
                (
                    "TableA_TableC"."IdTableA" = 
"TableA"."Id"
                )
            )
        )
        JOIN "TableC" ON (
            (
                "TableA_TableC"."IdTableC" = 
"TableC"."Id"
            )
        )
    )
    JOIN "TableB" ON (
        (
            "TableC"."IdTableB" = "TableB"."Id"
        )
    )
);
```

TableA.Id is the key inside of Monoblocks table

Comment: It's really unfortunate that this has not been addressed yet. :(